# How to emit less often the player position?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The multiplayer game I work with seems to transfer player screen position data all the time player moves with io.emit, I think this must be stress for server, how can I adjust this code to be executed no more than once per 250 ms?

```
    // Only emit if the player is moving
  if (this.speed != 0) {
      this.emitPlayerData()
  }              
},
emitPlayerData () {
  // Emit the 'move-player' event, updating the player's data on the server
  socket.emit('move-player', {
    x: this.sprite.body.x,
    y: this.sprite.body.y,
    angle: this.sprite.body.rotation,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `debounce` function.

```
if (this.speed != 0) {
  this.emitPlayerData()
}
```

would be

```
if (this.speed != 0) {
  debounce(this.emitPlayerData, 250, true)
}
```

Notice the debounce API, which is `debounce(expensiveFunction, ms, immediate)`

Example of a debounce function

```
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

For more information and examples:

- https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function
- https://gist.github.com/nmsdvid/8807205

If you're internally using lodash, go for it! https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce

Comment: "The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds" - would PlayerData be emitted if player keeps moving? Imagine player moving for 10 consecutive seconds, the PlayerData would not be updated during this period. Or am I misunderstanding the solution?

Comment: @Matus OP said _"seems to transfer player screen position data all the time player moves"_ so if he wants to stop the move event from firing before certain time threshold, he has to stop the function execution. A debounce function doesn't "stop" it, just "stack" all the invocations and executes the last one, after certain `wait` time. So if the player moved continuously for 10 secs, and the debounce function is set to `250ms` wait time, the event fired `1000 * 100 / 250` (40 times)

Answer (score 1):

You can create temporary timestamp to check what was the last time you emitted the data and only emit if it was more than 250ms ago. For example:

```
var lastUpdated = Date.now(); //get current timestamp
if (this.speed != 0 && lastUpdated + 250 <= Date.now()) { // if last updated timestamp + 250ms is smaller than current timestamp
    lastUpdated = Date.now(); //update the lastUpdated timestamp
    this.emitPlayerData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you can just ignore the emition of your specific event using something like

```
// Only emit if the player is moving
if (this.speed != 0)
{
    this.emitPlayerData()
}

var blockEmit = false;

emitPlayerData ()
{
    if (!blockEmit)
    {
        // Emit the 'move-player' event, updating the player's data on the server
        socket.emit('move-player', {
            x: this.sprite.body.x,
            y: this.sprite.body.y,
            angle: this.sprite.body.rotation,
        }
        blockEmit = true;

        setTimeout(function () {
            blockEmit = false;
        }, 250)
    }
}
```

It depends on how you are doing it and how you want to achieve it, but that's the main idea